# just grep multiple pattern on different row

Tags: linux, text-processing, grep

I have file.txt

```
A2
RP FAULT

A2
RP FAULT

A2
CELL

A2
CELL
```

how I can just grep 2 words: `A2 & RP FAULT`, The result should be :

```
A2
RP FAULT
A2
RP FAULT
```

what I try :

```
cat file.txt | grep -E "A2|RP FAULT"
```

but the result like this

```
A2
RP FAULT
A2
RP FAULT
A2
A2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `grep -E` command does what you wrote in the subject, but I guess what you really want is to show the `A2` lines with the "status" if the following line is `RP FAULT`. Right?

```
cat file.txt | grep -A 1 "A2" | grep -B 1 'RP FAULT'
```

The `-A n` shows `n` lines after the match, the `-B n` shows lines before.

Comment: you're right ..thanks bro , work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** You can try `pcregrep` instead of regular `grep`

```
pcregrep  -M "A2\nRP FAULT" file
```

- `-M` used to match across multiple lines so that we can search for newlines as `\n`.

**Option 2:** with regular `grep`

```
 grep -zoP "A2\nRP FAULT" file
```

Output:

```
A2
RP FAULT
A2
RP FAULT
```

Comment: ups ... pcregrep: command not found... need to install first

Comment: @AnggoroSetiawan then try option 2.